# How can I bind a ViewModel to an XAML file inside a ListView of another XAML file?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I genuinely was unsure how to search for this, so I'm hoping someone can understand my problem and either help or clarify if my approach is incorrect.

I have 2 XAML files (**ItemsPage** and **ItemTemplatePage**) and I'm wanting to bind each XAML file to a ViewModel (**ItemsPageViewModel** and **ItemTemplateViewModel**) - now this is simple when they're both separate pages, but in this example ItemTemplatePage is loaded inside a ListView on the ItemsPage for every Item in Items.

Obviously when I interact with an Item I will call the code behind for ItemTemplatePage but instead I would rather call a Command for ItemTemplateViewModel. However, when Items populate and bind to the ListViews ItemsSource in the ItemsPage, from what I understand that creates a BindingContext of Item for that specific template. So it's not like I can call in the constructor for ItemTemplatePage:

```
BindingContext = new ItemTemplateViewModel();
```

Because at this point it overwrites any binding done by ItemsSource from the ItemsPage; least that's what I've experienced so far.

Below is the code I have so far to provide an understanding from a code point of view, is what I'm trying to achieve doable or am I making it to complex for myself or have I misunderstand Binding and my approach is completely wrong?

Any and all help is highly appreciated!

===

**ItemsPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:template="clr-namespace:App.Views.Templates"
             x:Class="App.Views.ItemsPage"
             Title="All Items">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <template:Item />
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Contant>
</ContentPage>
```

**ItemsPage.xaml.cs**

```
Public ItemsPage() {
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new ItemsPageViewModel();
}
```

**ItemsPageViewModel.cs**

```
public class ItemsPageViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    private ObservableCollection<Item> items;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get => items; set => SetValue(ref items, value); }

    public ItemsPageViewModel() => DownloadItems();

    private async void Download() => Items = await API.GetItems(); 
}
```

**ItemTemplagePage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App.Views.Templates.ItemTemplatePage"
             Spacing="0">
     <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
     <Button Text="View" />
</StackLayout>
```

I've not provided the code behind for ItemTemplatePage.xaml because there is no additional code written here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` implements `DataTemplate`, which means that its contents are bound to the item, not to the page view model in general and that's how it should work, if you try to provide any other binding context it won't crash the app, but for sure app won't work as expected as you basically act against the logic of XAML that way.

Also your `ItemTemplagePage` is not a page at all (and shouldn't be), but for some reason you call it a page and that probably confuses you further.

Overall you need to work more to understand some basic terms and principles in XAML. I guess that you wanted to check if that's correct and that's fine.

Comment: Thank you for this understanding Ivan, from your explanation my approach does not seem doable. So this means I would be required to use the code-behind for ItemTemplatePage for any business logic?

I believe I understand where you're coming from when you refer to ItemTemplatePage not being an actual page. Is this because it's rather than the root tag being <ContentPage /> it is <Stacklayout />? I took this approach believing that it would make no sense to load a 2nd <ContentPage /> inside one already, am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: @MattVon it is hard / impossible to explain multiple basic concepts in one answer. But yes ItemTemplatePage can't have its own view model. You can put some logic at the data model if you really need to place it there, it feels most close to what you require.